# How is the complexity of applying Short term fourier transform over n samples with a moving window of size m amount to O(nmlogm)

Tags: fft, fourier

I have been trying to understand a publication [here](http://www.sigmobile.org/awards/mobicom2011-2.pdf) where Short time fourier transform is applied over n samples in steps of m samples each (m is the size of the moving window). I understand that the computational complexity of the Short time fourier transform for m samples is `mlogm`.

The operation also consists of extracting energy from the samples. Since there are m samples in the window, I believe it should be O(m) in the worst case.
So , as per my understanding, the complexity of the whole operation should be 
`O(n/m * (mlogm + m)) = O(nm)`. Since there n/m windows and each window has mlogm for fourier transform and m for signal strength extraction.

But the publication shows the complexity as `O(nmlogm)`. Please help me understanding this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

evidently the author is performing an FFT $n$ times (or, if the window hop is not 1 sample, it would be proportional to $n$) and each FFT costs something proportional to $m \log(m)$).  all this is quite normal.

Comment: Thanks,.. but wouldn't the number of window hops be just n/m given that the window size is m? Also, if in the worst case , m is 1 and FFT could be done n times.. that would lead to nmlogm but m = 1 would make it zero..

Comment: no.  the windows (or "frames") can overlap.  the degree of overlap is a parameter that someone sets for a particular purpose.  a 50% overlapping window would have a hop of $\frac{m}{2}$.  given a hop displacement of $k$ samples, the percent overlap would be $\frac{m-k}{m} \times$ 100%.  or you can derive the window hop displacement given the percent overlap.   but even if the hop displacement is a function of the window length $m$ or not, the number of windows (or frames) is $\mathrm{ceil}\left(\frac{n}{k}\right)$ which is virtually proportional to $n$.